# removing all files except files with a specific format with Bash

Tags: bash

```
cd ~/Downloads/
GLOBIGNORE=*.py
rm -v *
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

I've been trying to remove all files in a directory except for .py files using the command above.

It kinda works, but I also want to apply the same for the subdirectories.

How would that work?

Comment: Have you tried something in the order of `GLOBIGNORE=*.py */*.py` ?

Comment: `find ~/Downloads -type f -not -name "*.py" -delete`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use globstar and extglob (`shopt -s globstar extglob`):

```
rm **/!(*.py)
```